# How much can Lufthansa compensate in EUR for a cancelled flight & needing a day layover at a hotel?

Tags: layovers, cancellations, compensation

I had a 4-part flight booked with Lufthansa (src ->  VIE, VIE -> dst, dst -> VIE, VIE -> src). The last leg (VIE -> src) was canceled by them. I called to see what my options were, and they said that they can rebook a flight a day later. I said that I don't want to pay for a hotel for an issue that they caused. They said that I should pay for the hotel, save the receipt, and they will compensate me for the cost of a "reasonable" hotel (and food and whatever else is reasonable). I asked a few times how many euros is "reasonable", but they didn't say.

I assume that they in fact do have a limit, but this is a method that they use to discourage travelers from picking the most expensive hotel within that limit. I have no idea what a "reasonable" hotel costs. On booking.com I see from 23 EUR for a bed in a dorm, but if I look for a place with a single room, breakfast, high reviews, and other similar hotel amenities I see the prices start at 177 EUR.

I am willing to live below my comfort level if they will only compensate me for a dorm, but if they will compensate me for a nice 177 EUR (or more) hotel, I would much prefer that. So how many euros is "reasonable"?

ps. Same for food. I can eat cheep grocery store food, but would prefer to go to a sit-down restaurant.

Comment: If Lufthansa themselves can't tell you what Lufthansa consider a reasonable price, we certainly can't.

Comment: I suspect that it's not that they "can't", rather it's that they "wont". After all, they will be the ones deciding whether or not to compensate it.

Comment: I think the same applies regardless of whether you think they "can't" or "won't". And I must say, looking on booking.com for today and several other dates in the near future, I see absolutely no shortage of hotels in Vienna in good locations offering single rooms, including breakfast, with good (8.0+) reviews for significantly less than 177 EUR.

Comment: [Here](https://loyaltylobby.com/2018/12/16/compensation-clinic-lufthansa-ec261-compensation-2x-600-euro-incidental-costs-for-hotel/) an example of Lufthansa paying 170€ for an hotel so 177€ should be acceptable. Remember they owe you meals and transport to/from the hotel. They are also required to rebook you on the earliest available flight (even if that means upgrading you or rebooking you on a different airline in some cases) and that you are quite likely to be owed compensation (depending on the actual delay at arrival and the cause of the delay).

Comment: I think there is no "EUR" value for *reasonable price*. Often we see real last minute (so evening) booking are much more expensive, and it depends on season, city, etc.. Do a screenshot of booking (of google map, with hotel prices), and reasonable would be a mid range price (and probably slightly more).

Comment: Lufthansa cancelled the first leg of my trip in Dec and rebooked me onto a flight 3 days later that required an overnight stay (arrival into FRA 20:30, onbound flight departing 10:00 the next day). Their agents said the same thing about recovering the hotel cost. I booked into one of the airport hotels, which cost 280€ given very short notice. I’ve just returned from my trip and submitted my claim. Waiting to see if they blame weather disruption (no other flight departures cancelled that day however, AFAIK) in order to reject hotel + delay compensation

Comment: Something like single room, breakfast, relatively close to the airport or inner city, maybe 3 stars should be reasonable. You do not need to sleep in a dorm.

Comment: Airlines have a duty of care, so if you need to stay overnight somewhere because of something they did, then they have to provide you with a hotel. So when arriving in Vienna, go to the LH service desk and ask them where they are going to book you...

Comment: @Traveller if they claim extraordinary circumstances, they can get out of the compensation, but not of paying for the hotel.

Comment: One potential way to assess this are the per-diem rate that governments determine Here the rates that the US government uses for Austria. https://aoprals.state.gov/web920/per_diem_action.asp?MenuHide=1&CountryCode=1072 . It would be hard to argue for an airline that official government rates are "ureasonable"

Comment: @Hilmar thanks, that's definitely very very "reasonable". I should have no problem finding a hotel for 300 EUR a night.

Comment: @KristvanBesien I would prefer to pick my own hotel ahead of time, and not rely on whatever the agent in Vienna gives me. It will also give me peace of mind to know that I have a place waiting for me, and that I won't find the airline staff on a break and have to fend for myself.

Comment: @jcaron note that in my case I am not stranded. Maybe I wasn't clear, but I haven't started my journey yet. They offered to rebook my last leg 1.5 days later. I am perfectly okay with a free Vienna vacation. I just want to know how much I can "reasonably" splurge on a hotel.

Comment: @Hilmar on the contrary, a room rate at the maximum per diem rate will be easily dismissed as unreasonable. A simple check on booking.com yields several hotels which are more than suitable for a simple overnight stay due to a cancelled flight (single room, breakfast, good connection to the airport), and cost only around €100. While the Lufthansa Callcenter might not know what prices are reasonable, it is likely that the department that issues the compensations *will* check.

Comment: @jcaron Lufthansa has refused me compensation on the grounds that the flight cancellation was weather-related. They've offered me 150€ to cover my hotel, which leaves me 130€ out of pocket for the unplanned hotel stay in FRA, plus a wasted £145 for the hotel in Manchester the night before my original flight. LH hasn’t explained how they’ve determined the €150 payment

Comment: I think Lufthansa would be hard pressed, @Traveller, to blame the OPs delay on weather since the flight cancellation for the return leg was made before the outbound leg even started...

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, here is my recent experience with Lufthansa.

Outbound first segment of flight MAN>FRA>HOG cancelled 8pm on the evening before scheduled 6am departure to FRA, *after* I had checked in my luggage using their ‘sundowner’ option and *after* I had checked into the airport hotel in MAN. I was re-booked onto the next available connecting flight, arriving into FRA at 20:30 to connect with the Holguin flight departing 10am the next day. This meant an overnight stay in FRA. Given the late-ish inbound arrival plus early check-in for the onbound flight, I booked into an airport hotel at 279€. The flight re-booking meant I arrived at my final destination three days late.

- Initially Lufthansa offered me 150€ towards the FRA hotel cost. They said the cancellation was weather-related and refused compensation. They didn’t explain how they arrived at the amount offered for the hotel cost.
- I rejected the offer, as it left me 120€ out of pocket, plus the £145 I had spent on a hotel at Manchester on the evening before my original flight.
- Lufthansa increased their offer to 279€, which I have accepted - it is ‘reasonable’ and covers the extra costs I incurred due to the cancellation/re-booking. Payment is due to my bank account within 10 days.

Conclusion: my situation was really an unplanned overnight transit. If the re-booking had meant I’d have a longer layover in FRA, I would have looked for a cheaper hotel.

Comment: I guess an anecdotal story is the closest to an answer that I can get. I booked a place for 117 EUR. Wish me luck (I'll update after the trip)